# What is the color type that i get from Buffer, using MediaCodec

Tags: java, colors, android-mediacodec

I'm followed [this example](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest.java.txt) in order to understand how to work with MediaCodec.

This example works fine for me except 1 thing, I don't know how to figure what is the color type after I'm grabbing the frame from the buffer.

this is how I grab the frame(Java):

```
        GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            mPixelBuf);
        mPixelBuf.rewind();

        int[] colors = mColorSwapBuf;
        mPixelBuf.asIntBuffer().get(colors);
```

my question is:
how do I know what type of color I've got?

This is example for the input: color[0] = 0xffd2c8bc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a 32-bit RGBA value.  Sort of.

When `glReadPixels()` extracts the data, it grabs a byte of red, then a byte of green, and so on.  The frame grab code is treating it as little-endian, so you get `0xAABBGGRR`.  The swap code in the original swaps the B and R channels, leaving you with `0xAARRGGBB`.

In your code sample you don't do the swap, so you're still in ABGR format.  For your example, that would mean A=0xff, B=0xd2, G=0xc8, R=0xbc.  You can convert this to individual channels by swapping bytes around.  You could also use a byte[] rather than an int[] and just access each color individually (buf[0] through buf[3] is red-green-blue-alpha for pixel 0, buf[4] through buf[7] is for pixel 1, etc).

Comment: Thank you very much this is very useful!
So if I want to convert my image to gray,Is this how I can do it?
      `B = (col >> 16) & 0xff;
      G = (col >> 8) & 0xff;
      R = col & 0xff;
                inputarray[i] = (int)(((((R*0.3) + (G*0.59) + (B*0.11)))));`